# wrong conversion in strtotime & in date() for 1345810203

Tags: php

I want to store start time & end time and calculate the total time difference between the two times.Some time i got negative times like `-1 min -24 sec` by this problem...

if i am echo this code

```
date('Y-m-d h:m:s',1345810203);
```

i got the answer as `2012-08-24 02:08:03` ,but i echo this code

```
strtotime('2012-08-24 02:08:03');
```

i got the answer as `1345766883` .

If the time will be `1345810167` or `1345810187`,give correct time in strtotime & date().

What is the problem ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have wrong format.

`m` is `Numeric representation of a month, with leading zeros`

`i` is `Minutes with leading zeros`

Use following format:

```
'Y-m-d h:i:s'
```

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Third coffee does its job. 8-)

Comment: @rhrobert You're welcome. Also you should mark the correct answer with a tick below answer's score. You should do it also with your recent questions !